# Are there any main benefits/consequences for storing large arrays in cookies

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies

My dashboard preforms the same ajax requests on every page load (things that AREN'T specific for that page).

For example, Facebook-like notications, basic stats, new messages count, etc.

I am considering storing all this information in their cookies. The information is not private or secure so I'm not worried about cookie stealing.

My users are connected to a socket, so I'll be able to notify them to erase the cookie and reload the ajax when something new comes.

I realize I can avoid most of these ajax requests using a framework like Angular. For now, I'm just looking for a quick solution.

What are the main problems I could run into from doing this? Is this a common thing?

EDIT: Just FYI, I am using memcached on server-side to prevent excess database-use. I just thought it would be neat to skip the ajax altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of cookies is to piggyback on every request from the client to the server. Thus, they make a poor way to store information that you don't need the client to send back to the server.

[Web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), which is [extremely well-supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage), is the way to store information on the client that you only need to use on the client. You can store up to 2.5MB or 5MB, depending on the browser, which I'm guessing is more than enough for your use case.